# How to add text to a CSS Sprite

Tags: html, css, text, css-sprites

I'm creating a blogger template shown here: http://aergaergerg.blogspot.com.au/  and as you can see the buttons for 'featured posts' are empty. I was wondering how I'd add text to them through the html gadget itself, or css, or whatever is possible. Some might suggest to just include the text within the picture, except my problem is that since it's 'featured posts' obviously the links are going to change a lot. Here's a picture of what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Anyway, here's the HTML for the featured post buttons (css sprite):

```
<!--Social Sprite Html2-->
<div id="head-soc2">
<ul>
<li id="Button1"><a href="http://www.spaceheroesfansite.com/p/about.html">3</a> </li>

<li id="Button2"><a href="http://www.spaceheroesfansite.com/p/promo-codes.html"></a>    </li>

<li id="Button3"><a href="http://www.spaceheroesfansite.com/p/game-tricks.html"></a></li>

<li id="Button4"><a href="http://www.spaceheroesfansite.com/p/purple-jacket-squad.html"></a></li>

<li id="Button5"><a href="http://www.spaceheroesfansite.com/p/purple-jacket-squad.html"></a></li>

</ul>

<!--Social Sprite Html2--></div>
```

And the CSS for it:

```
/*Social Sprite Css Buttons*/
#head-soc2 ul li {list-style :none; padding: 0px; float: center;}
#head-soc2 ul li a {text-indent: -9999px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; overflow: visible ; border: 0; background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D2V1j-OWhrM/UqYsp5RVMuI/AAAAAAAADgI/IsObrayuepI/s1600/bannersprite2.png") no-repeat; display:     block;}


#head-soc2 li#Button1 a{background-position: -787px 0px;height:  51px; width: 204px;     margin-bottom:15px;}
#head-soc2 li#Button1 a:hover {background-position: -787px -51px;height:  51px; width: 204px}

#head-soc2 li#Button2 a {background-position: -787px 0px;height:  51px; width: 204px;     margin-bottom:15px;}
#head-soc2 li#Button2 a:hover {background-position: -787px -51px;height:  51px; width: 204px}

#head-soc2 li#Button3 a {background-position: -787px 0px;height:  51px; width: 204px; margin-bottom:15px;}
#head-soc2 li#Button3 a:hover {background-position: -787px -51px;height:  51px; width: 204px}

#head-soc2 li#Button4 a {background-position: -787px 0px;height:  51px; width: 204px; margin-bottom:15px;}
#head-soc2 li#Button4 a:hover {background-position: -787px -51px;height:  51px; width: 204px}
#head-soc2 li#Button5 a {background-position: -787px -102px;height:  51px; width: 204px; margin-bottom:15px;}
#head-soc2 li#Button5 a:hover {background-position: -787px -102px;height: 51px; width: 204px}
```

and if it helps here's a JSFiddle :)  http://jsfiddle.net/8xZDL/

Thanks!

Comment: @codehorse This question really has nothing to do with sprites, except that's OPs strategy for implementing the background images. It is better described as "why doesn't my text show up in these buttons"; The answer being that the font size is set to 0 and the text is indented 9999px off the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think the following CSS is your problem. I feel like you mighta been able to figure this out if you stuck with it for a bit. Just pull those 3 rules out and it works

```
#head-soc2 ul li a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
```

Comment: thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that! I'm only a beginner in coding

Comment: no worries! I know it sometimes takes me a whole day to find a capitalization error hahah... Good luck on your project!

Comment: Sounds like you should maybe walk through some [tutorials for CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). There are a whole slew of `font-` *rules* that can be set in combination with `margin`s, `padding`, `line-height`, `text-indent`, `color`, etc.. Browsers support only a handful of (crappy) fonts by default, but you *can* include others with a bit of magic. Check out ["Google Fonts"](http://www.google.com/fonts) for one of the best collections of such fonts.